# Can a user be identified on the basis of token?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is a noob question. I an working with a rest api service using nodejs. I have read about tokens. I do not understand how do web sites identify a user. Consider this. I  have user specific data at my end. Now a user logs in and I verify his/her credentials using my database. Then I return a token to it. Now in the subsequent requests only the token arrives,**so how do I know which user's data has to be accessed?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/introduction/) to store some user basic data (such as its ID or role).

Then, here is the processus:

- The user log in and retrieve a JWT
- The token is stored in the user's localStorage or cookies
- On each next request, you need to send the token in the HTTP header `Authorization`
- For each request, you need to check this token on the backend
- To logout, you just need to delete the token in the localStorage or the cookie

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic to it, token you have to store somewhere, in modern architecture we usually use DB because we are getting away from sessions since we have to think horizontal scaling where session management gets problematic across servers.

So here is  what you can do

1. Return the user token after he/she logs in and saves that token in the user collection(?)
2. Subsequent calls would have that token in the header
3. With that token query the user collection and see if it's a valid user or valid token. With each call you can also maintain timestamp making sure the duration between two calls should not be more than a set time duration. Hence simulating server session. though that's optional.

However in case you are using mongoDB, there could be additional way.

1. Maintain a separate collection for session,
   holds the token and other details(user-agent,ip etc.) in the document.
2. put a unique index on the token field.
3. Maintain a timestamp field let's call it **sessionTimeOut** and add a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) over that field for set duration(say 1 hour).
4. Now next time you get the token in the header, with the token try to update(not upsert) the sessionTimeOut field by additional set duration(1 hour).
5. Check how many records were updated in write result, if 0 records, it means session was expired so send the client appropriate message to login again.
6. If it updated one record, then the session is elongated for 1 more hour

The benefit of this model are few

1. At any point you can see who all are logged in.
2. If you make it a capped collection, you can sort of define how many user can login at a single time in your application. (though it's unnecessary)
3. Your user table won't be unnecessarily hit for user validation with each call specially if you put basic user detail in the token related collection.
4. TTL index deletes the expired user, so the collection would never be too big.